# Need help setting up multi-VPN solution

Tags: networking, vpn, streaming

Ok so here is my network rough sketch.

[image: sketch of network]

Location 1 has 125/125 fiber connection, location 2 has 300/25 cable connection.

GOALS:

- I want every device at both locations to be able to access the plex server to stream movies (or at the very least be able to transfer a file from the server to a local machine for playback)
- Both PS4's should be able to play online without NAT issues, and also be able to stream from plex
- I need the HTPC at loc1 to appear to be on the loc2 network so that I can view local locked out content
- Video streaming (netflix,youtube,etc) should be HD, and there should be no extra lag for gaming.

Is this possible? How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking is done plenty of times by businesses and is a site-to-site VPN... which there are many tutorials available

1. You don't need VPNs in both directions. One end will be the VPN server and the other will be the VPN client. The VPN equipment can be configured to "always enabled" which means the client device will always try to connect if the tunnel is down. Get the connection(s) up and configure a VPN trunk - this will give you improved bandwidth (if you have more than one ISP) and/or failover/redundancy.
2. As you have a site-to-site VPN you would need to configure both sites to be in different subnets (A: 192.168.0.x -> B: 192.168.1.x) and then configure the VPN to route the subnets - all your equipment will be able to communicate as normal if you've configured the routes correctly.

Comment: Wouldn't this allow every device to communicate with every other device?

Comment: Yes, which from your "GOALS" is (kind of) what you're asking, right? VPNs don't work in "directions". The only "direction" they work in is which side initiates the connection to create the tunnel (the client initiates a connection with a server and (all going well) a tunnel can be created).

Comment: No I only want them all to have access to the plex server, the rest of the devices should be isolated in their lans.

Comment: Your equipment will need to be able to provide VLAN or complex routing capability, if this granular access is required. You should also update your question stipulating precisely what should access what and, more importantly, what shouldn't be able to access what. Your question, as it stands, looks like you want both sites to be able to access all resources (essentially).